# HttpWebResponse.StatusCode is "OK" when server actually returned "Unauthorized"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC action, I returned "Unauthorized" as the ActionResult:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Wrong activation code");
```

On client side, I checked HttpWebResponse.StatusCode:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            else
                MessageBox.Show(response.StatusDescription, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

But "response.StatusCode" is always "OK". Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. "Unauthorized" caused my website to redirect the request to the login page, and the login page returned "OK"